# Refactoring block of jQuery code?

Tags: jquery, refactoring

I have a section of jQuery code that I am having to repeat over and over with only a small change accompanying each iteration. Here is an example of what I have:

```
  if($('.smm').hasClass('vendor-icon-active')) {
      total = total + 1200;
  } else {
    total = total;
  }

  if($('.repman').hasClass('vendor-icon-active')) {
      total = total + 495;
  } else {
    total = total;
  }

  if($('.blog-management').hasClass('vendor-icon-active')) {
      total = total + 395;
  } else {
    total = total;
  }

  if($('.press-release').hasClass('vendor-icon-active')) {
      total = total + 195;
  } else {
    total = total;
  }
```

In my code, I have about 30 of those sections. Is there a way I could simplify that process and clean up my code?

Comment: the else is not needed, that would instantly reduce the size of your code quite a bit.

Comment: Oh really? So it work if I just kept the if statement?

Comment: Yup. The else literally does nothing in this case.

Comment: Yes because inside the `else` you are just setting `total = total;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a common class to group the elements, and a `data-*` attribute to hold the value associated with them. Try this:

```js
var total = 0;
$('.item').each(function(i, el) {
  var $item = $(el);
  if ($item.hasClass('vendor-icon-active')) {
    total += +$item.data('value');
  }
});
console.log(total);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="smm vendor-icon-active item" data-value="1200">Foo</div>
<div class="repman vendor-icon-active item" data-value="495">Foo</div>
<div class="blog-management vendor-icon-active item" data-value="395">Foo</div>
<div class="press-release vendor-icon-active item" data-value="195">Foo</div>
```

Comment: Oh yeah that actually looks great! is data-value supported by older versions of IE?

Comment: you could use 'vendor-icon-active' as the common class so you won't need the if hasClass

Comment: @AbrahamUribe that's true for my example, although it would depend on the OPs DOM structure.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick...

```
function updateTotal(className, value) {
    if ($('.' + className).hasClass('vendor-icon-active')) {
        total += value;
    }
}

updateTotal("ssm", 1200);
updateTotal("repman", 495);
updateTotal("blog-management", 395);
updateTotal("press-release", 195);
```

I just moved the main functionality into that one function.  You can add as many function calls as you need afterwards :)

Comment: I do prefer @RoryMcCrossan's answer, but this gives you options and 2 very different styles of getting the same result.